# Performance of descendants search using Postgres intarray field

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a Postgres (ver. 9.5.4) table `geo` which contains 738,884 records of country geo data with the following structure:

```
              Table "public.geo"
   Column    |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                     | not null  | plain    |              |
 kind        | character varying(255)      |           | extended |              |
 name        | character varying(255)      |           | extended |              |
 is_owner    | integer                     |           | plain    |              |
 path_array  | integer[]                   |           | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "geo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "kind_index" btree (kind)
    "path_array_idx" gin (path_array gin__int_ops)
```

Records have hierarchy by `kind` field: `country` -> `province` -> `area` ->  `locality`. This hierarchy stored in `path_array` field as array of ancestors and row's self ids.

Example:

```
17239123    locality    Moscow  1   {17073865,17073877,17073958,17239123}
```

I have installed [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html) extension and added proper index to `path_array` field.

Now I have a bunch of ids of recods that can have any kind (from country to locality) and I need to select all their descendants with type `locality` (i.e. records that have any of this ids in their `path_array`).

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT
    id
FROM geo
WHERE
    kind = 'locality'
    AND is_owner = 1
    AND path_array && '{17073888,17073984,17073885,17073905,17073958,17073927,17073908,17073952,17073948,17073947,17073917,17073944,17073919,17073922,17073914,17073937,17073895,17073904,17073911,17073949,17073938,17073957,17073900,17073915,17073936,17073887,17073933,17073939,17073956,17073884,17073901,17073881,17153202,17073916,17073945,17073883,17073943,17073909,17073950,17073942,17073906,17073886,17073910,17073882,17073941,17073891,17073929,17073928,17073903,17073912,17073930,17073898,17073899,17073954}'::integer[]
```

Here is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on geo  (cost=1418.04..1532.99 rows=8 width=4) (actual time=685.183..723.330 rows=20984 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: ((is_owner = 1) AND (path_array && '{17073888,17073984,17073885,17073905,17073958,17073927,17073908,17073952,17073948,17073947,17073917,17073944,17073919,17073922,17073914,17073937,17073895,17073904,17073911,17073949,17073938,17073957,17073900,17073915,17073936,17073887,17073933,17073939,17073956,17073884,17073901,17073881,17153202,17073916,17073945,17073883,17073943,17073909,17073950,17073942,17073906,17073886,17073910,17073882,17073941,17073891,17073929,17073928,17073903,17073912,17073930,17073898,17073899,17073954}'::integer[]))
Filter: ((kind)::text = 'locality'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 2037
Heap Blocks: exact=17106
->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1418.04..1418.04 rows=29 width=0) (actual time=681.154..681.154 rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on is_owner_index  (cost=0.00..544.24 rows=29309 width=0) (actual time=5.493..5.493 rows=29201 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (is_owner = 1)
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on path_array_idx  (cost=0.00..873.54 rows=739 width=0) (actual time=667.888..667.888 rows=607440 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (path_array && '{17073888,17073984,17073885,17073905,17073958,17073927,17073908,17073952,17073948,17073947,17073917,17073944,17073919,17073922,17073914,17073937,17073895,17073904,17073911,17073949,17073938,17073957,17073900,17073915,17073936,17073887,17073933,17073939,17073956,17073884,17073901,17073881,17153202,17073916,17073945,17073883,17073943,17073909,17073950,17073942,17073906,17073886,17073910,17073882,17073941,17073891,17073929,17073928,17073903,17073912,17073930,17073898,17073899,17073954}'::integer[])
Planning time: 0.212 ms
Execution time: 727.370 ms
```

The above query took about 700 ms, which I believe is very slow.
Am I right or I ask for too much?

Comment: According to the explain plan the query only took 700ms, not 1.4 seconds

Comment: It was network latency issue. Fixed it and added possible solution.

Comment: looks good to me -- afaiac, go ahead and post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created complex index on path_array and is_owner fields.

```
CREATE INDEX path_array_owner_idx ON geo USING gin (path_array gin__int_ops) WHERE is_owner = 1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Bitmap Heap Scan on geo  (cost=436.04..550.99 rows=8 width=4) (actual time=30.292..68.778 rows=20984 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((path_array && '{17073888,17073984,17073885,17073905,17073958,17073927,17073908,17073952,17073948,17073947,17073917,17073944,17073919,17073922,17073914,17073937,17073895,17073904,17073911,17073949,17073938,17073957,17073900,17073915,17073936,17073887,17073933,17073939,17073956,17073884,17073901,17073881,17153202,17073916,17073945,17073883,17073943,17073909,17073950,17073942,17073906,17073886,17073910,17073882,17073941,17073891,17073929,17073928,17073903,17073912,17073930,17073898,17073899,17073954}'::integer[]) AND (is_owner = 1))
   Filter: ((kind)::text = 'locality'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2037
   Heap Blocks: exact=17106
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on path_array_owner_idx  (cost=0.00..436.04 rows=29 width=0) (actual time=25.923..25.923 rows=23021 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (path_array && '{17073888,17073984,17073885,17073905,17073958,17073927,17073908,17073952,17073948,17073947,17073917,17073944,17073919,17073922,17073914,17073937,17073895,17073904,17073911,17073949,17073938,17073957,17073900,17073915,17073936,17073887,17073933,17073939,17073956,17073884,17073901,17073881,17153202,17073916,17073945,17073883,17073943,17073909,17073950,17073942,17073906,17073886,17073910,17073882,17073941,17073891,17073929,17073928,17073903,17073912,17073930,17073898,17073899,17073954}'::integer[])
 Planning time: 0.219 ms
 Execution time: 72.956 ms
```

Now the above query took 70 ms, which is nice.